# How to refactor multiple if statements to decrease cognitive complexity

Tags: java, if-statement, sonarqube

SonarQube doesn't allow too many if statements as the cognitive complexity is too high.
What would be the best approach to refactor it?

I have If statements that check if value is not null. If it's not - it should call `rejectValueIf()` method.

```
if (body.getCprNumber() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getCprNumber().size() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.CPR_NUMBER,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getCvrNumber() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getCvrNumber().size() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.CVR_NUMBER,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getId() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getId().size() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.ID,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getSize() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getSize() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.SIZE,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getNext() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getNext().length() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.NEXT,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getPage() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getPage() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.PAGE,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getSortFields() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getSortFields().size() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.SORT_FIELDS,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getFields() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getFields().size() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.FIELDS_CONSTANT,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getSearchParameters() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getSearchParameters().size()
            > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.SEARCH_PARAMETERS,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getLimitSearchToFields() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getLimitSearchToFields().size()
            > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.LIMIT_SEARCH_TO_FIELDS,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getMaxSize() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getMaxSize() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.MAX_SIZE,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);

  if (body.getDefaultSize() != null)
    rejectValueIf(
        body.getDefaultSize() > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
        errors,
        ValidationConstants.Fields.DEFAULT_SIZE,
        ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);
}
```

My only idea is to make an array with all the values, then check which indexes are not null and then create a switch case loop. Is there some better way?

Comment: You should consider throwing away SonarQube. This is a very simple code with no cognitive complexity whatsoever. Solutions suggested by others don't look less complicated even though they don't have that many if-statements. That being said.. you may want to consider BeanValidation instead of validating fields manually. Though the fact that your validation uses dynamic values means you'd have to create your own validators & annotations. Still, if this is a very common theme in your project, that would probably simplify things for the readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it can be extracted as a private method:

```
// you can probably think of better names than I do
private <T> void validateSize(T field, Function<T, Integer> sizeMapper, String validationConstant) {
    if (field != null)
        rejectValueIf(
            sizeMapper.apply(field)
                > contactIndexConfigurationProperties.getBulkSearchLimit(),
            errors,
            validationConstant,
            ValidationConstants.ErrorCodes.NUMBER_OF_SEARCHES_NOT_ALLOWED);
}
```

I have assumed that things like `ValidationConstants.Fields.SEARCH_PARAMETERS` are `String`s. If they are not, please change the type of the third parameter accordingly.

Then you can just call this method instead of those if-statements.

```
validateSize(body.getCprNumber(), CprNumber::size, 
    ValidationConstants.Fields.CPR_NUMBER);
```

I have assumed that `getCprNumber` returns a `CprNumber`. Again, if it doesn't, please change `CprNumber::size` to a method reference of the correct type.

In cases like `getMaxSize` where you don't call an additional `size()` or `length()` method, pass `Function.identity()` as the second parameter instead.